# GNU Screen list all users - attached/detached?

Tags: serial-port, gnu-screen

how can I list all users processes in *screen* such that I can see if process is attached/detached?

Problem with **-ls** is that, it doesn't list all users. When I do **ls /var/run/screen/S-*userName***. I can see processes, but I can't see if they attached/detached. Also I need to do it for all users.

- Note 1: I can't use any CTRL + * combination, because of my projects purposes.
- Note 2: I use screen for serial port communication over /dev/ttyUSB*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out it and for anybody who need it:

There is command in Linux:

```
su - userName -c 'screen -ls'
```

It will display all attached/detached screens for any user. But you need to be root as well.

Actually it is not full solution. But it works well. You'll need to run(as root) it for all users you want.

Answer (score 2):

Screen is designed to be per-user so that multiple users can be using multiple screens without being able to affect each other's sessions.

From what I can tell you can list another user's sessions but NOT whether they're attached or not:

```
root@host:~# screen -list username/
There are screens on:
        9124.pts-2.host     (28/07/15 22:34:42)     (Private)
        9110.pts-2.host     (28/07/15 22:34:37)     (Private)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-username.
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But actually it doesn't  useful in my case, thanks.